# In-app purchase with iPad

Tags: ipad, in-app-purchase

I have followed ["http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases%22) link for in-app purchase.

This works fine with iphone

but in iPad I am able to make in-app purchase.It is displaying that "Cannot connect to itunes" (in ipad only)

Can any one know why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what exactly the problem is

1. Maybe you are using wrong Test User
2. Maybe there is a problem in Sandboxing
3. Maybe you should just Hard reset (Settings => General => Reset => Erase All Content and Settings).

Try to look for different solutions on stackoverflow, there are dozens of them on your request